# How to fix my vim theme

Tags: ubuntu, vim

[image]

I'm working with an ubuntu 16.04 VPS which I access via windows through Putty. I'm trying to install http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized but I'm getting terrible contrast(screenshot for solarized light).  After following the instructions on installing via pathogen (Option 2: Pathogen installation (recommended)). How can I get this theme working properly?

my .vimrc:

```
syntax enable
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

Edit:

my .vimrc:

```
syntax enable
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
highlight Normal ctermbg=Blue
```

Comment: What's on your `~/.vimrc`?

Comment: Please see edit:

Comment: I see a lot of tips on the link you provided.  Did you try `let g:solarized_termcolors=256`?  Did you follow the vim instructions on http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized? Have you tried "setting your terminal emulator’s colorscheme to used the Solarized palette," Have you tried tweeking the settings on `Putty > Change Settings > Window > Colours?

Comment: For me, `set background=dark` is easier on my eyes. [What are the negative and positive aspects of dark color scheme?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8153/what-are-the-negative-and-positive-aspects-of-dark-color-scheme)

Comment: Thanks guys. I eventually found http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-syntax and http://alvinalexander.com/linux/vi-vim-editor-color-scheme-colorscheme, which helped me . I eventually just added "highlight Normal ctermbg=Blue" to my .vimrc and it now is readable

Comment: I'm going to guess that your putty isn't configured to allow 256 colors, or your `$TERM` isn't set to something that supports 256 colors.

Comment: @user61629 you should post your terminal config and your vim config so that we can help you. If you set something in solarized to blue, it defeats the whole purpose...

Comment: Hi Mike , my full .vimrc is in the edit above. I'm not sure what you mean by  terminal config ..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to read the "important note for terminal user" section of [the page you linked](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized). In summary, the terminal version of the Vim theme assumes that your terminal colors are already set to Solarized (e.g. using the `Xdefaults` file).

If this is not the case then you can force the theme to approximate Solarized palette using the 256 available colors by adding this to your `.vimrc`:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

Note that this only applies to Vim on the terminal (not GUI like GVim or MacVim).